# wp_set_post_terms struggle :(

Tags: terms

I have trying to find that one without luck for a while therefore I come to you.

when I try to insert a term as custom taxonomy it doesn t work completely.
If I write this

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $county, 'kommun');
```

basically I don t think it completely works as I can see the term when I am editing a post individually in the admin area. 
But when I see the list of all posts in the admin area, in the table the term is not appearing although the custom taxonomy column is there.

Now when I do

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $county."test", 'kommun');
```

everything works normally...

When I echo $county, the value is a normal string...

any thoughts? thanks

best,

alexis

Answer (score 0):

Just by posting.. I made a final test.
And I suspected a conflict somewhere in the custom taxonomy names, what I did is I changed the name of the custom taxonomy in **function.php**

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $county, 'kommun1');
```

is working well :-)

I got so focused on the variable. my bad...

have a nice day